# I want to make a Cornu spiral in blender using nodes

Tags: geometry, nodes, blender, spiral

And I have no clue where to start. In case you don't know what a cornu spiral is: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html

All that I see are intrincated maths whose terms I'm not familiar with and doesn't translate as far as I know directly to blender interface which also I don't know in depth.

I had some success setting the handle absolute positions given point position on the bezier but I have no idea how to relate them in order to achieve my goal. Can you lend me any formula to calculate the correct brezier handle positions relative to point position and also the positions of the points? I'm about a week on this and I'm still starting.

Comment: How do you calculate point positions? With parametric equation against `t` ?

Comment: How do you do equations in BHlender? whith the math module. does it calculate integrals? no, next method.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Could you show how points are calculated?

Comment: Sorry, I underestimated your answer, all this has me anxious. I did litle advance on this over python but nothing that I wrote myself just copypasta. The good thing is that now I have the Spiral and I'm on the process of convert it to a svg path. About your question, it's a parametric equation given by a definition that I don't understand and you should read in order to answer your question. All that I know is that it's calculated along s or t (terminoilogy is killing me) and it's given from the fresnel equation for x and y aka the integral of the cosine and sine of the heading angle of start

Comment: respectively. The fact is that I don't know integrals and defining curves is far from my current understanding and focus. What I explained to you is what I could understand from that script in python and the wikepedia.

Answer (score 0):

We can draw Cornu spiral using small line segments. Example in Delphi:

```
  cx := 10;
  cy := 700;
  scale := 700;
  step := 0.02;
  Canvas.MoveTo(cx, cy);

  for i := 1 to 250 do begin
    t := i * step;
    fresnelintegral(t, c, s);
    x := cx + Round(scale * s);
    y := cy - Round(scale * c);
    Canvas.LineTo(x, y);
  end;
```

here `t` is curve parameter (proportional to arc length), and we calculate coordinate of current point using Fresnel integrals and scaling (to make a picture of viewable size). This code generates black curve:

[image]

If we want to approximate Cornu spiral by Bezier curves, we have to get endpoints with the same equations, then get direction angles in previous point and in the current point (slope equation (2)  in your link) to define intermediate control points. But we also need to calculate distances to control points - seems rather hard problem. I made quick code to demonstrate an approach.

Curvature of Cornu spiral rises along the curve. To approximate spiral better, I had to diminish steps, so Bezier segments become smaller and smaller. Small circles are Bezier endpoints, they become closer.

I tried to make `coeff` depending on `t` value, but have not found good equation. The code below generates blue curve. It is very close to black one (we can align them) in chosen `t` range.

```
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlue;
  cx := 500;
  step := 0.2;
  prevt := 0;
  t := 0;
  Canvas.MoveTo(cx, cy);
  Pts[0] := Point(cx, cy);

  for i := 1 to 70 do begin
    t := t + step;

    fresnelintegral(prevt, c, s);
    prevx := cx + Round(scale * s);
    prevy := cy - Round(scale * c);
    prevfi := 0.5 * Pi * prevt * prevt;

    fresnelintegral(t, c, s);
    x := cx + Round(scale * s);
    y := cy - Round(scale * c);
    pts[i*3] := Point(x, y);
    fi := 0.5 * Pi * t * t;
    Canvas.Ellipse(x-2, y-2, x+3, y+3);

    coeff := 1/3;
    dist := Hypot(x - prevx, y - prevy) * coeff;

    px := prevx + Round(dist * Sin(prevfi));
    py := prevy - Round(dist * Cos(prevfi));
    pts[i * 3 - 2] := Point(px, py);

    px := x - Round(dist * Sin(fi));
    py := y + Round(dist * Cos(fi));
    pts[i * 3 - 1] := Point(px, py);

    step := step * 0.96;
    prevt := t;
  end;
  Canvas.PolyBezier(pts);
```

Comment: Hi there, I read your answer many times and this time more carefully, I already have come to my own solution by means of naif steps.  It's not that I'm null in math, it's just that integrals and turns are generally far from my interests, indeed my mind struggles even with the most trivial when compiting turns are involved at anything. I explain this just to tell that I understanded the essential of your appraoch and that is however similar to mine.

Comment: I started by taking the python script broadcasted here: https://medium.com/@alejandro.blumentals/computing-clothoid-curves-in-five-lines-of-python-3ea762debaa1

Comment: It's fairly simply and well explained. as you see it calculates the fresnel integrals from integrating cos(theta*s) and sin(thetha*s) to x and y respectively. I don't have a clear idea about what it comes out from the ode integrate function because I havent given it enough time, all that I know is that it works! and so I got more intrested about the fresnel equation and I think that I figured out that tyhere's a simple expression behand al that elegancy meaning e^(i*pi*x**2)/2 = pi*x²+pi*x²*i, more or less like saying integrate this function for x and y

Comment: I'm better at arithmetics and abstract algebra that at calculus, so I developed the fresnel integration further at the sightt that if he is using polar coordinates to describe a circle transversing tangent along a path and diminishing it's radius over the normal then I could describe a sphere doing the same using spherical coordinates instead of polar coordinates. Hence now I also have an angle of tortion phi so x turns to be t*cos(phi)*sin(theta), y turns to be t*sin(phi)*sin(theta, and z=r*cos(theta), integrate this and you may have a fresnel equation in three dimensions.

Comment: Anyway I'm still on the details over this and I don't know how accurate could be my reasoning. I came over the blender part by using it's python api, don't ask much to that program. The good thing is that I tested it and it works and now I have euler spirals that not only bends over the xy plain but also twists over the xz plain by an equivalent function. However the result is not as intresting as you may think, just an increasing curvature that twists some degrees at every turn resuling in a small ball pf points at the end instead of the characteristic circle.

Comment: I'm still on my way way to make them look more intresting and replicate the "polinomial spirals" particular cases of cornu spiral cited at this article: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CornuSpiral.html given by this relations https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/equations/CornuSpiral/Inline33.svg and giving these results : "polynomial spirals" And I'm looking for the in any convenient dimension aka 2d would suffice.

Comment: But as I said before I stil don't get what a cesaro equation is nor I have a clear sight about what the definitions for arc length curvature and tangent represent in the partricular case as they imply an "n" factor that it's not well defined in this context and that I ignore if it's a variable, a constant or a function. If you understand this please try to explain because indeed this is the real question of my post.